# why is this controller instantiated only once?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras

I have the following (also in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EwtPwwMeqZxifOLveYhX)):

```
<!doctype html>
<html 
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="theApp">
    <div ng-conroller="ExampleCtrl as ctl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="ctl.value"/><br>
      {{ctl.value}}
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl as ctl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="ctl.value"/><br>
      {{ctl.value}}
    </div>
    <script>
     angular.module('theApp', [])
            .controller('ExampleCtrl', [
              function () {
                var self = this;
                self.value = 'Lorem ipsum';
                console.log('controller instantiated');
              }
            ]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Looking at the console, I see only one message `controller instantiated` and only the second inbox has the bound value printed below it:

[image]

I was expecting two separate controllers to be instantiated and indeed after filling-in values it appears that there's two independent scopes, however I cannot explain the initial state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typo in first `ng-controller` directive declaration.

```
<div ng-conroller="ExampleCtrl as ctl">
```

should be

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl as ctl">
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/LDvbeB7OSnGAsd55lw7Z?p=preview)

Comment: Upvoted but I'm gonna delete the question. It adds nothing to the community.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus It may assist the person who might have made spelling  mistake like you :) and its common sort of spelling mistake as angular directive doesn't have intellisense on IDE..

Comment: yet it is weird that after the initial loading, one can type values in the first field or second field and see two different values being printed. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus because both were using different controller initialization of different DOM.. you are creating two instances of same `controller` which `context` is sharing on different `DOM`s

Answer (score 1):

thats because of typo:

The first controller is spelled as: `conroller` instead of `controller`